# How to extract this field from this string format?

Tags: python, regex

```
[{"answerInfo":{"extraData":{"am_answer_type":"NN"}},"content":"MP3：not support.","messageId":"c4d6a2f4649d483a811fcce4b26ae9a1"}]
```

How to extract "MP3: not support" from this String using regular expression or python code?

But an error was generated per the suggestion:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/congminmin/PycharmProjects/Misc/csv/csvLoader.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(question+ " " + json.loads(answer)[0]['content'])
  File "/Users/congminmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/congminmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/congminmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: if("MP3：not support" in yourStr) print 'yay'

Answer (score 1):

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun 17 2018, 12:13:06)
>>> text = '[{"answerInfo":{"extraData":{"am_answer_type":"NN"}},"content":"MP3：not support.","messageId":"c4d6a2f4649d483a811fcce4b26ae9a1"}]'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(text)[0]['content']
'MP3：not support.'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `json` instead of `regex` based on your sample.

Check it [running here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1SKCe987)

```
import json

json_data = '[{"answerInfo":{"extraData":{"am_answer_type":"NN"}},"content":"MP3：not support.","messageId":"c4d6a2f4649d483a811fcce4b26ae9a1"}]'

python_obj = json.loads(json_data)
print(python_obj[0]["content"])
```

Comment: @user697911  I added a link for you to be able to see it running, I believe you might have special characters and encodings that made errors